# How to generate a resume after an applicant submitted an online resume?

Tags: 7, nodes, log-messages

I'm currently building a recruitment system using Drupal 7. In my system, an applicant who wants to apply for a job, needs to complete an online resume (one time only).

Question: Are there any modules that can generate a simple resume after the applicant finishes (saves) the online resume, similar to this [Online resume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuPyv.jpg) example?

Comment: I don't think you are going to find something already build to do this.

Comment: @pere do u know where i can refer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a profile type using [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) module and call it something like 'Resume'. So that every user can create a Resume profile for themselves.

Then I would install [Print](https://drupal.org/project/print) module and enable Print PDF and set it to show up on Resume profile pages.

You must play with the permissions so that only the owner of the profile can access the profile page and the PDF version. You may have to write some custom code to make PDF version accessible only once. You may achieve this writing an access callback function for the PDF path.

Comment: dude, this is awesome! thank you very much! its work for me..

Comment: @Izzwan If it works for you, you can mark this answer as accepted (the green check sign, on the left side of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the profile2 based approach, you may want to consider the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module. Reason why I think so, is because the question was tagged with the [reports](/questions/tagged/reports) tag.

It would probably take a bit of time to achieve perfection, but you'd have all of Forena's xHTML-power available to finetune the ultimate result (CV?), for things such as:

- look-and-feel (styling/theming).
- granularity of who is allowed to see what subset of data contained in the CV (what forena calls data blocks, and the related permissions that can be added to each block).
- maybe add some charts to it also (using selected data stored in the CV).
- saving the ultimate output (CV) in formats such as PDF, DOC, etc.
- creating eMail campaigns about selected CVs.
- puling in information stored in other databases related to this CV.

For more details about Forena, 2 types of documentation are available:

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://www.forenasolutions.org) for an online example of the current:

  - **Forena documentation** - use the link 'Reporting documentation' or visit relative link /reports/help.
  - **Forena samples** - use the link 'Reporting samples' or visit relative link /reports/samples (these samples are fully functional, so make sure to experiment a bit with it, such as the drill downs available on the SVG Graph sample).

The newest 7.x-4.x version also includes an amazing (I think) UI for either creating your reports (the WYSIWYG report editor) and/or for creating your SQL queries (the Query Builder).

Here is some more info about the **other databases** in mentioned above:

1. Using a **SQLite** instead of MySQL database: the Forena samples actually get shipped including a (Tiny) SQLite database. Go check it out in the [demo site](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/samples): the data shown there are data contained in the sampledb, which is in SQLite format.
2. Forena comes with a full suite of [Supported database connections](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363#dbconnections) ... such as MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle, Postgress or any PDO compliant variation.

Enough reasons for considering giving Forena a try? While doing so, use it's issue queue for any type of support/docu requests you may have.

**Be aware**: I'm a co-maintainer of Forena.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with [Recruiter](https://drupal.org/project/recruiter) Module

> Recruiter is a Drupal distribution for building Drupal based e-recruitment platforms. Users can register either as recruiter and post job classifieds or they can register as applicants and fill out their resume. A faceted search helps users to find jobs and possible job candidates.